# Absolute positioning does not allow checking checkbox

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I have 2 checkbox inside a div with absolute position style.
Then when I try to check them I'm not allowed.
I tried to remove the position just for the checkbox but it doesn't work.

```html
<div style="position:absolute">
  <div class="apr-laflex-container apr-and-text-ellipsis-container">
    <div>
      <span>Status<span>
   </div>
  </div> 
     <div class="apr-laflex-container apr-and-text-ellipsis-container">
   <div>
    <span>StartDateFrom</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>StartDateTo </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="ScheduledOperation">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Scheduled Operations" checked>
        <label for="Scheduled Operations">Scheduled Operations</label>
      </div>
      <div class="UnscheduledOperation">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Unscheduled Operations">
        <label for="Unscheduled Operations">Unscheduled Operations</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: "I'm not allowed"??  "it doesn't work"?? And where is your CSS that does the absolute positioning?

Comment: Post your CSS please

Comment: Can you please provide the one example

Comment: It's probably a z-index problem, but without css is impossible to know. Maybe this layer is below another layer and the clicks goes to the layer above.

Comment: Right click the checkbox and then "inspect".... The most likely cause is that you are not actually clicking the checkbox, instead, there is probably another HTML element on top of it that is capturing the click event. Alternatively, try giving the check box a style="z-index: -1" and see if that solves it.

Comment: The example provided works

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you're referring to, but the `for` attribute on the labels needs to match an `id` on the `input type="checkbox"`. I changed the for names to camelcase, since the id can't contain spaces, but really you want `for` and `id` to be shorter strings.

```html
<div style="position:absolute">
  <div class="apr-laflex-container apr-and-text-ellipsis-container">
    <div>
      <span>Status<span>
   </div>
  </div> 
     <div class="apr-laflex-container apr-and-text-ellipsis-container">
   <div>
    <span>StartDateFrom</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>StartDateTo </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="ScheduledOperation">
        <input id="scheduledOperations" type="checkbox" name="Scheduled Operations" checked>
        <label for="scheduledOperations">Scheduled Operations</label>
      </div>
      <div class="UnscheduledOperation">
        <input id="unscheduledOperations" type="checkbox" name="Unscheduled Operations">
        <label for="unscheduledOperations">Unscheduled Operations</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```